# turnjs4 flipping page disables my scripts

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, turnjs

I'm building a website that looks like a book using [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com). Each page is a `.php` file that utilizes `javascript` for page-turning effects.

Initially, all of my scripts work just fine. There are two pages in particular that are causing me problems though. A page with a list of books, that, when you click on them it displays a description, and an FAQ page that has clickable questions and displays the answers when clicked.

When I flip to page 9 and onward, and then flip back to the books page or FAQ page, the descriptions and answers javascript won't work anymore.

I've tried removing the javascript from one page and flipping pages still disables the other page's javascript so I know the javascript isn't a problem. So what else could disable my javascript?

Also a link to the site that I am building http://www.jalbertmann.com

**UPDATE**

So I have further established that this seems to be an `AJAX` related problem. [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com) uses `AJAX` to fill the pages(divs) of the book like website with the content of other `.php` files. I have local `scripts` within these files and for some reason they only pass once. When I got to certain pages, the `scripts`, as I wrote above, fail. Is there anyone that can help me? I don't know enough about [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com)'s or `AJAX`'s documentation.

Comment: Found a solution!
turns out `turn.js` automatically set `pagesInDOM = 6 (line: 107)` which for some reason makes JavaScript and other things disable after page 6 and 9. Changing to  `pagesInDOM = 1000 (line: 107)` everything should work perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turn.js` automatically set `pagesInDOM = 6` (line: 107) 
Change this to `pagesInDOM = 1000` (line: 107)

related file: turn.js

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! 
`turn.js` automatically set `pagesInDOM = 6` (line: 107) which for some reason makes `JavaScript` and other things disable after pages 6 and 9. Changing to `pagesInDOM = 1000` (line: 107)
Everything should work perfectly!